# Ndb entry .put() not executed?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm facing an issue I can't explain. The best is with some code :

```
class MyEntry(ndb.Model):
    entry_id = ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=True)
    treated = ndb.BooleanProperty(name="is_treated", default=False, indexed=True)

    @classmethod
    def find(cls, entry_id):
        return cls.query().filter(cls.entry_id == entry_id).get()


def treat_entry(id):
    entry = MyEntry.find(id)

    entry.treated = True
    entry.put()

    logging.info("Entry {0} treated!".format(id))
```

Now, the `treat_entry` method is called a lot, like 20/30 times per minutes (I have a lot of entries to treat), and here's what I discovered :

I saw on the log of AppEngine that the line

> Entry 4 treated!

was written, but when I go see on the datastore for entry_id = 4, the `treated` variables is still at `false`.

How is that possible? I believed that `put()` would fail if there was any issues. Is there some reason why `treated` is `false` despite my code saying otherwise ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: you know about eventual consistency? Sounds like it could be that. Does it eventually change? How quickly are you checking?

Comment: I can't say if the value changed. I believe its possible since the amount of queries is made, that there could be an override, except that I only query by the id, and in the logs, there is only one "Entry 4 treated!" for all the process tested.
If writing an other row made changes to that one, there could be some problem, but if it only affect the current row, this id 4 is used only once. (Hope that clears things)

Comment: I don't really understand, sorry.

Comment: THere are no rows, just entities. Please look at @paulcollingwood's suggestion.  Read up on what eventual consistency means.  There are hundreds of questions on SO about this topic.  You are performing a query which is not guaranteed to get the latest data.  Therefore you can be overwriting older value.  Also your code doesn't check for not found.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884076/google-datastore-queries-and-eventual-consistency